# Why won't ggplot render the fill color of this reactive plot correctly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to create a `shiny` app that plots a selection of data in a `ggplot` bar graph. Each row of data represents the number of aphids of a single taxon found on a single plant (plants are grouped into sites). I want the bars to show the total count of aphids at each site. The bars should be filled by taxon, i.e. each bar should be made of one or more colors, corresponding to the proportion of aphids within each taxon at that site. I'd like to make some other changes, too - but right now I'm stuck on this problem.

The problem is that `ggplot` doesn't like how I've specified reactive data as the fill aesthetic. Oddly enough, it seems to work just fine if I use the color aesthetic instead of the fill aesthetic. Why won't this same approach work for the fill aesthetic? Is this a bug?

```r
library(shiny)

#### UI side here ####
ui <- fluidPage(

  checkboxGroupInput('year', 'Choose a year', choices = c(2017,2018),
                     selected = c('2017','2018')),
  checkboxGroupInput('taxon', 'Choose a taxon', 
                     choices = c('Acyrthosiphon sp.','Aphis craccivora',
                                 'Therioaphis maculata','Unknown'),
                     selected = c('Acyrthosiphon sp.','Aphis craccivora',
                                  'Therioaphis maculata','Unknown')),
  plotOutput('bars'),
  plotOutput('bars2')

)
?reprex

#### Server side here ####
server <- function(input, output) {

  library(tidyverse)
#### Subset of my data for reprex ####
  data <- structure(list(year = c(2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 
                                  2018L, 2018L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 
                                  2018L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
                                  2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L, 
                                  2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L), site = c(122L, 
                                                                                             109L, 148L, 121L, 150L, 138L, 153L, 153L, 107L, 113L, 136L, 146L, 
                                                                                             114L, 107L, 113L, 148L, 106L, 146L, 151L, 120L, 139L, 138L, 144L, 
                                                                                             142L, 144L, 143L, 153L, 138L, 124L, 107L, 138L, 144L, 150L, 121L, 
                                                                                             108L, 107L, 135L, 113L, 146L, 147L), plant = c(20L, 26L, 27L, 
                                                                                                                                            2L, 20L, 17L, 27L, 12L, 10L, 4L, 2L, 25L, 17L, 16L, 9L, 26L, 
                                                                                                                                            14L, 18L, 26L, 1L, 29L, 4L, 27L, 16L, 23L, 17L, 16L, 1L, 19L, 
                                                                                                                                            19L, 20L, 8L, 13L, 18L, 30L, 17L, 21L, 3L, 23L, 24L), taxon = structure(c(3L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Acyrthosiphon sp.", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "Aphis craccivora", "Therioaphis maculata", "Unknown"), class = "factor"), 
                         count = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
                                   4L, 11L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
                                   1L, 158L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), 
                         long = c(-105.561694, -120.290645, -106.085614, -111.79121, 
                                  -119.372752, -111.478175, -112.763, -112.763, -111.623191, 
                                  -119.995186, -119.89852, -119.768389, -118.78077, -111.623191, 
                                  -119.995186, -106.085614, -111.791825, -119.768389, -111.013924, 
                                  -120.478646, -111.477622, -111.478175, -117.134722, -117.802018, 
                                  -117.134722, -117.741105, -112.763, -111.478175, -110.937281, 
                                  -111.623191, -111.478175, -117.134722, -119.372752, -111.79121, 
                                  -122.485552, -111.623191, -115.02496, -119.995186, -119.768389, 
                                  -111.415287), lat = c(41.634862, 41.98567, 38.722843, 40.579933, 
                                                        38.753147, 41.009581, 47.92386, 47.92386, 41.609366, 39.51379, 
                                                        39.507393, 39.466116, 39.45819, 41.609366, 39.51379, 38.722843, 
                                                        41.728298, 39.466116, 43.17306, 40.288588, 40.529525, 41.009581, 
                                                        39.220556, 41.569559, 39.220556, 40.979555, 47.92386, 41.009581, 
                                                        42.005173, 41.609366, 41.009581, 39.220556, 38.753147, 40.579933, 
                                                        41.765685, 41.609366, 38.87951, 39.51379, 39.466116, 40.492409
                                  )), row.names = c(221L, 109L, 639L, 211L, 693L, 415L, 781L, 
                                                    769L, 60L, 127L, 352L, 585L, 148L, 63L, 130L, 638L, 43L, 577L, 
                                                    746L, 198L, 441L, 399L, 537L, 479L, 534L, 498L, 771L, 397L, 231L, 
                                                    67L, 418L, 513L, 685L, 217L, 99L, 66L, 342L, 126L, 581L, 610L
                                  ), class = "data.frame")

  rdata <- reactive({
    subset(data, year %in% input$year & taxon %in% input$taxon) %>%
      arrange(site, taxon)
  })

#### Here's the broken part #####
  ## This one (using fill) doesn't work.
  output$bars <- renderPlot({
    p <- ggplot(data=rdata()) +
      geom_bar(aes(x = rdata()[,'site'], y = rdata()[,'count']),
               fill = rdata()[,'taxon'], stat = 'identity') + 
      coord_flip()
    print(p)

  })

  ## This one (using color) does work. ???
  output$bars2 <- renderPlot({
    p <- ggplot(data=rdata()) +
      geom_bar(aes(x = rdata()[,'site'], y = rdata()[,'count']),
               color = rdata()[,'taxon'], stat = 'identity') + 
      coord_flip()
    print(p)

  })


}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I expect the bars to be filled by aphid taxon, but instead I'm getting the error "invalid color name 'Acyrthosiphon sp.'" ('Acyrthosiphon sp.' is one of the taxons). Since this column contains factor data, shouldn't ggplot be automatically assigning fill colors to the factor levels, just like it does for the color aesthetic?

Comment: Do you observe this behaviour also outside of shiny? Please try to test it. Also, if you specify esthetics explicitly (`rdata()[,'taxon']`), there is no need for data in the ggplot call - use `ggplot(data=NULL)`. This often helps in such situations, since ggplot then does not try to interpret the esthetics as variable names and takes them for what they are (vectors).

Comment: As FJCC pointed out in the rstudio community forum [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/why-wont-ggplot-render-the-fill-color-of-this-reactive-plot-correctly/35206), the code `p <- ggplot(data=rdata()) + geom_col(aes(x = site, y = count, fill = taxon, stat = 'identity')) + coord_flip() print(p)` seems to work just fine. This still leaves open the question of why the original version doesn't work, though. Perhaps @January is on the right track. I'd be curious to learn what was going on, if anyone ever cares to figure it out.

Comment: I don't know enough of ggplot2, but when you have a construct `ggplot(data, ...) + geom_xxx(aes(x=data[,yyy])....` weird things tend to happen. I have seen it many times. Never bothered to really dig into this matter, though.

Comment: FWIW, the fill aesthetic doesn't work for me either, eg in a call such as: ggplot(myData, aes(x = xData, y = yData, fill = InfectionStatus, color = Timept, shape = cellType)) +  geom_point(size =3)). All the markers are filled in, and the legend taunts me with correct labels ("infected" and "uninfected") but both the legend markers for this feature are filled in, too.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `fill` option to the `aes`:

```
geom_bar(aes(x = rdata()[,'site'], y = rdata()[,'count'], fill = rdata()[,'taxon']),
         stat = 'identity')
```